Why am I having an issue with typescript and Prisma ORM when trying to find a unique item?
I am having issues with my ability to use the prisma .findUnique() function call. My code doesn't show any compilation error, but when I actually try to go to a product page it causes a runtime error.
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.product.findUnique()` invocation:

{
  where: {
    id: "6"
        ~~~
  }
}

Argument `id`: Invalid value provided. Expected Int, provided String.

I am using the product id, which is an int, but from what it seems, .findUnique() thinks it is a string? So I was wonding what I can do to make .findUnique() work?
This is my schema.prisma file, showing my schema
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model Product {
  id          Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name        String   @db.VarChar(127)
  description String   @db.VarChar(511)
  imageUrl    String   @db.VarChar(255)
  price       Int      @db.SmallInt
  createdAt   DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime @updatedAt

  @@map("products")
}


and this is where I am trying to find an item by id.
interface ProductPageProps {
  params: {
    id: number;
  };
}

const getProduct = cache(async (id: number) => {
  const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({ where: { id } });
  if (!product) notFound();
  return product;
});

export async function generateMetadata({
  params: { id },
}: ProductPageProps): Promise<Metadata> {
  const product = await getProduct(id);

  return {
    title: product.name + "Project",
    description: product.description,
    openGraph: {
      images: [{ url: product.imageUrl }],
    },
  };
}

export default async function ProductPage({
  params: { id },
}: ProductPageProps) {
  const product = await getProduct(id);
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col gap-4 lg:flex-row lg:items-center">
      <Image
        src={product.imageUrl}
        alt={product.name}
        width={400}
        height={400}
        className="rounded-lg"
        priority
      />
      <div>
        <h1 className="text-5xl font-bold">{product.name}</h1>
        <PriceTag price={product.price} className="mt-4" />
        <p className="py-6">{product.description}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}



I have tried converting the number to a string and then passing that into .findUnique(), just on the off chance I actually need it to be a string for some reason.
 const stringId = id.toString();
 const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({ where: { stringId } });

but then I get an error of
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'stringId' does not exist in type 
'ProductWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2353)

index.d.ts(1548, 5): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared
 here on type '{ select?: ProductSelect<DefaultArgs> | null | undefined; where: ProductWhereUniqueInput; }'

No matter what, it seems to be a type error of some kind, and I am at a loss. What can I do to overcome this issue?

Try passing the id like this:
const product = await prisma.product.findUnique({ where: { id: +id } });

It would work like breeze.
